# VectorType attribute with dynamic dimension ML.NET

Tags: c#, .net, machine-learning, ml.net

I am working on training and evaluation in ML.NET. The data comes from a .csv file.
According to the requirements, there may be variable number of columns in the file. Until now, I have achieved this by providing a fixed vectorType dimension. But I am not aware of making this work dynamically.

Here is the a block of code working using the fixed dimension,

```
public class InputClass 
{
    public bool isChecked;
    
    [VectorType(5)] 
    public string[] records;
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
   MLContext mlContext = new MLContext(seed:0);
   TextLoader.Columns[] columns = new TextLoader.Columns[2];
   columns[0] = new TextLoader.Column("isChecked", DataKind.Boolean, 0);
   columns[1] = new TextLoader.Column("records", DataKind.String, 1,5);

   IDataView dataview = mlContext.Data.LoadFromTextFile(filepath, columns,        
   separatorChar:',', hasHeader:true, allowQuoting:false, trimWhitespace: true, 
   allowSparse:true);

   //-- creating pipeline and training a model further

}
```

This code works without any issue. But I just need the VectorType to accept the dimension at runtime. Now it accepts only constant values.
I am looking if there is any workaround to achieve this.
I am a beginner into ML.Net, please do understand if I missed any steps or anything to be explained.
I really appreciate any help to get this worked.

Comment: I really appreciate any help if anyone knows any workaround for this problem

Comment: I sympathise with you. I cannot understand the thinking behind ML.NET which requires you to write a new object class for each data set you want to explore. It removes all ability to dynamically explore data. Plus, questions about ML.NET posted here seem to get no response from Microsoft, which is worrying. For what it is worth, you may want to see my solution to your problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57238348/ml-net-build-and-train-model-using-datatable-with-feature-columns-only-known-at/57246898#57246898 (not completely dynamic, but goes some way towards it)

Comment: I ran across this post on github in case you missed it: https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/issues/164

Answer (score -1):

Building off of [github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/issues/164](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/issues/164), this is working for me in a similar situation.

```
var schemaDef = SchemaDefinition.Create(typeof(InputClass));
schemaDef["Records"].ColumnType = new VectorDataViewType(NumberDataViewType.Single, 5);
```

where the class needs a columnname attribute:

```
[VectorType(5)] 
[ColumnName("Records")]
public string[] records;
```